# Issue with offset top on chrome

Tags: jquery

I get an issue with `òffset().top` property in jQuery. It works on every browsers except Chrome.

I'm working on a table, so the `offset().top` will be on cells...

My code :

```
var topOfCell = $('td').offset().top;
var bottomOfCell= $('td').offset().top + $('td').outerHeight();
```

Result on Chrome :

[image]

Result on Firefox, ie, ect...

[image]

Comment: a jsfiddle would be better.

Comment: Are you accessing the `offset()` in your `$(document).ready` event? I think they should fire on `$(window).load` event (for Chrome). Look it up, could be worth a shot.

Comment: on `$(document).ready` event... I try...

Comment: Ok so it works with `$(window).load`, but why? Thank's a lot ;)

Comment: I had problems with Chrome too.. I think it's due to that other browsers can access the DOM immediately but Chrome need it to be "fully loaded".. but `$(window).load` makes the DOM accessable immediately.

Answer (score 2):

offset() method gets the position relative to the document and may vary browsers to browsers, so using position() method would solve your problem which gets the position relative to parent offset. And for this you should apply the css position in your parent element.

So, try using [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method

Or, may be the offset top is getting the value before the content loaded so try using it on ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//do stuff here
});
```

Or, try using it on window load function:

```
window.onload = function(){
//do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: "window.onload" was great help for me